# 'double-conversion/double-conversion.h' file not found

Tags: swift, react-native, mapbox, native

For a turn-by turn navigation/gps app I'm trying to combine React Native and MapBox Directions SDK.

Now I found a couple of medium post about how to bridge RN to Swift. The last couple of days I've been trying to combine them but in every method I use this 1 error pops up all the time:

```
'double-conversion/double-conversion.h' file not found
```

The weird thing is that React-native builds fine without self-written code. After I wrote my own code it just breaks on this error.
Has someone of you guys had this before??

I'm using RN 0.60.4 . I've also tried older versions of RN but when I try to install my pods it doesn't generate my .xcworkspace

Thanks in advance ;p

Comment: See the relevant issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25349

Answer (score 2):

According to [React Native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25349#issuecomment-519014463):

> You are using the RN version (0.60.4) which does not work with use_frameworks!. I suggest removing use_frameworks! from your Podfile or using the lastest RN from master.

Moreover, Facebook officially tracks the issue. It is said in [release notes](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#cocoapods-by-default).

> Note that we are aware of a compatability issue with use_frameworks!, and we're tracking an issue with workarounds and a future patch.